# Dependency issues between keras-nlp and tensorflow when running preset-model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pip, dependencies

I am trying to follow some example code of keras-nlp to use a pretrained built-in BERT model.

```
bert_classifier = keras_nlp.models.BertClassifier.from_preset("bert_tiny_en_uncased")
```

However, I have some difficulties with the dependencies and versions of the required packages (keras-npl, keras, tensorflow, tensorflow-text and tensorflow-intel).

When starting a new virtual environment and running `pip install --upgrade keras-nlp` and
`pip install --upgrade keras>=3` PIP returns an error message:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow 2.10.1 requires keras<2.11,>=2.10.0, but you have keras 3.0.4 which is incompatible.
```

Upgrading tensorflow to version 2.15 with `pip install --upgrade tensorflow` installs keras 2 (and removes keras 3), and gives a new PIP dependency error message:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow-text 2.10.0 requires tensorflow<2.11,>=2.10.0; platform_machine != "arm64" or platform_system != "Darwin", but you have tensorflow 2.15.0 which is incompatible.
```

I tried installing specific versions of keras-npl, keras, tensorflow, tensorflow-text and tensorflow-intel. No matter what I do I get dependency issues in PIP and error messages when running the example python script. The websites https://pypi.org/project/keras-nlp/ and https://keras.io/getting_started/ could not clarify this issue for me.

Which versions do I need of all these packages, or in which order should I install them?

Answer (score 0):

> However, I have some difficulties with the dependencies and versions
> of the required packages (keras-npl, keras, tensorflow,
> tensorflow-text and tensorflow-intel).

while dealing with multiple packages and their versions, can be a challenging task. However, some guidance on how to approach resolving these dependency conflicts.

**NOTE**:-Different versions of packages might have specific compatibility requirements.

So,you're encountering conflicts between TensorFlow, Keras, tensorflow-text, and keras-nlp

First you need to find compatible versions of `TensorFlow, Keras, TensorFlow Text`, and any other required packages that work well together.

Compatible versions [Document](https://mckayward.github.io/floyd-docs/guides/environments/)

Install a specific version of TensorFlow that is compatible with both keras-nlp and tensorflow-text.

Use This Examples Commands:-

> pip install tensorflow==2.10.0

Install keras-nlp and keras:

> pip install keras-nlp keras

Install tensorflow-text:

> pip install tensorflow-text==2.10.0

Once all dependencies are installed without conflicts, try executing your example Python script again to verify if it operates as intended.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip:
"Caution: TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on native-Windows. Starting with TensorFlow 2.11, you will need to install TensorFlow in WSL2, or install tensorflow or tensorflow-cpu and, optionally, try the TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin"

Although TensorFlow 2.15 is available as a pip package but not for Windows
i managed to install tensorflow-cpu which will upgrade your installation to 2.15 and import will go fine, but unfortunately it doesn't come with tensorflow-text which is required for keras3 subcomponents, for example code like:
tokenizer = keras_nlp.models.BertTokenizer.from_preset( "bert_base_en_uncased", )

will not work without tensorflow-text greater than 2.10